# Is there anyway to save environment variables in vscode jupyter before shutting down kernel?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm working with jupyter notebook on vscode and have multiple large files to load and I'm aware that I could capsulate processed data with frameworks such as pickle, etc. but was curious if there is anyway to store jupyter environment variables on disc, and restore them on next use to avoid waste of time and processing power?

Comment: have you checked `os.environ` after `import os`. You can pickle it to disk. Best to use pyenv with .env file to create a virtual environment and use that.

Comment: maybe you could check this storemagic [link](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html), not sure how good it works with large variables.

Comment: thanks @Rock, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: nice that you find your answer.